# Pretentious vs Superficial

Tags: meaning, synonyms

From what I Understand , both these words in a day to day vocabulary describing a Person

**Pretentious** means Someone who is trying to get more importance by pretending something or Exaggerating something.

**Superficial** means something just on the surface, ie. Pretending something but you do not truly believe in that thing. Maybe to show Something your not(which in turn becomes pretentious?)

Seems like one is a Synonym to another,but it is not.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ELU!  Did you have an actual question about these two words?

Comment: Yes, Well look i feel like these are synonyms, but internet suggests these are not. So is there only this slight difference

Comment: There is a huge difference. This question is out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These words are absolutely not synonyms. Using them as such can land you in a lot of trouble, if you mistake superficial for pretentious. If you make the mistake the other way around, you might be unnecessarily generous.

You can be *superficial*, which simply means *without depth*, without being *pretentious*, which means *attempting to impress with qualities beyond one's own*.

For example, you could say *"his treatment of the subject was superficial"* to mean that the topic was not discussed in depth. It may have been deliberately kept at that level -- *superficial* has no connotation in this case.

When used as a generalization about someone, *"He is very superficial"*, then *superficial* has negative connotation.

Someone who is "*pretentious*" does not need to be *superficial*. If their depth is sufficient then *pretention* is usually replaced by *arrogance*.

Comment: Good answer +1. But I am just wondering if the OP actually meant *supercilious*, which is closer in meaning to *pretentious* than *superficial* is.

Comment: No, i meant Superficial. Good Answer. Does clear alot of doubts. But when used as a generalization, wont Superficial mean Pretentious. I mean Being Superficial , the person would be like that for some reason, mostly to impress. Maybe theres a thin line, or maybe just depends on the perspective?

Comment: Being superficial need not have any alterior motive, it may be how a person is: Preferring not to plumb depths.